# How to create a scope to order cities name?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have two models/tables: Services and City

Service model:

```
belongs_to :origin_city, class_name: 'City'
belongs_to :destiny_city, class_name: 'City'
```

How do I create a scope to order cities name?

I'm trying something like that:

```
scope :by_city_name, -> { joins(:city).order("cities.name asc") }
```

But I just want to order the service origin city in one scope. And service destiny city in another scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should join only `origin_city`:

```
scope :by_origin_city_name, -> { joins(:origin_city).order('cities.name asc') }
```