# How to build scope to order title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am trying to create a scope that will order by the `title(:title)`. The title column resides in the Post Model. I read through the [scopes section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) on the Active Record querying section and the [one on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816930/how-to-create-a-scope-to-order-cities-name) but it is not quite clear.  Can someone point me in the right direction possibly?

I have 4 models:

```
Comment
Post
User
Advertisement
```

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :title, :user
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user

    default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}
    scope :ordered_by_title {order('title' )} #What I initially built
end
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you do not have any `default_scope` with `order`:

```
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { order(title: :asc) }
```

When you have a `default_scope` with `order` then you need to use [`reorder`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reorder):

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { reorder(title: :asc) }
```

or `order` with [`unscope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#unscope):

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { order(title: :asc).unscope(:order) }
```

The `reorder` method overrides the default scope order.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately simple `order` will not work. Active Record allows you to specify multiple orders on a single association (which will order firstly by `created_at` column and then by `title` - second ordering will not change anything in this case). You need to tell rails that you want to ignore previous order statement using `reorder` method.

```
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { reorder(title: :asc) }
```

Comment: This needs more visibility! Use `reorder` if your ActiveRecord association already has an order applied to it. It's very possible that if you find yourself needing to use `reorder` instead of plain `order` that you have a default scope in your model, which is a no-no.